# almost sure convergence concepts applying to possibly non random variable

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, measure-theory

I have a question about almost sure convergence of something.

Basically it is coming from confidence interval.

I was reading that $\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} I_{\{\bar{x}-1.96, \bar{x}+1.96\}} (\theta_i) >=0.95 $ almost surely for any sequence of $\theta_1, \theta_2,...$

My question is what does the almost sure convergences here means? because when I learned about almost surely convergence, I learned it from the concept of a random sequence of random variable say $X_1, X_2,...$ converges almost surely to $X$ if $ P(w: \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} |X_n(w) - X(w)| \geq \epsilon) = 0$.

My question is where is the $X_1, X_2,...$ in my limit infimum of the sequence of indicator here? or what are the sequences that I should be looking at here?

Because I cannot translate from the convergence of almost surely of a sequence of random variable to my example.

Could someone comment.

Thank you

Edit (in response to Whuber):

So does it means the statement is saying this:

$P(\liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} I_{\{\bar{x}-1.96, \bar{x}+1.96\}} (\theta_i) >=0.95 )$ = 1?

But if the statement is saying the above here? may I know what is the epsilon and the $X$ in my case? I think I know the $X_n$ in my case that corresponds to the $X_n$ in the definition of the almost surely convergence of random variables. But not clear about the $X$ and the $\epsilon$.

Comment: Presumably the "$\bar x$" in your limit refers to the arithmetic mean of a set of random variables.  Thus, the terms in the summation are random variables, too, whence almost sure convergence means what it always means.  BTW, the "$0$" in the lim inf likely is intended to be "$\infty.$"

Comment: Hello, but if the infimum of the average of the indicator of n variables are my sequence of $X_1, X_2,...$, may I know what is the $X$ variable that I have here? i.e. what is the variable that the sequence of $X_1, X_2,... $ converges to?

Comment: The sequence of variables is the sequence of the averages, not a sequence of infima.  This question concerns a [limit inferior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior), not a limit.

Comment: OH, thanks. But may I know what is the "$\geq 0.95$" corresponds to in the definition in the almost surely convergence in my case here? also what is the $X$ in the definition of almost surely convergence in my corresponding case here? Because I am still not quite clear about what does the almost surely means in my example when it says the limit inferior of that sequence of average of indicator functions will be bigger than 0.95 almost surely.

Comment: To say that a random variable $X$ lies *almost surely* in a set $\mathcal A,$ such as the set $\mathcal{A}=[0.95, \infty),$ means that $\Pr(X\in\mathcal{A})=1.$

Comment: I think I understand what limit inferior means, it means the average of the sequence of the later terms. For example I guess my $X_1$ here would mean the average of the sequence of the indicator functions of all the terms. And my $X_2$ here is the average of the sequence of indicator functions here without including the first term. And my $X_3$ would be the average of the sequence of indicator functions here without including the first two terms (i.e the first two indicators functions),.....